# Update files from server to server

Tags: rsync, upgrade, scp

I am building a tool using bash script, to move the files from server to server. But the tool for update, so I don't want to overwrite the exist files, in the other server from the first moment. I actually want to move it then replace the files.
Does `rsync` or `scp`, have some option to deal with this? Or do I need to write another script to do that in the destination server??

Comment: You want to move them? In what way? And are you going to upload the files anyway even if they were already there? You might be better of using some existing software that keeps revisions on the remote server like rdiff-backup.

Comment: Hi @Anthon , Actually I want to move them any way, if the files are exist or not. But if the files already there I don't want to  replace it right a way. Because that's will break my site if any one access it while I the script is running. Also  rdiff-backup wouldn't help here, since I am using the script from another server.

Comment: I am using rdiff with storage on the remote server, does exactly that what you describe.

Comment: Thanks @Anthon this actually did the job very well. I can see it from this  [link](http://www.nongnu.org/rdiff-backup/examples.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use --backup and --suffix parameters for rsync:

```
-b, --backup        make backups
--backup-dir=DIR    make backups into hierarchy based in DIR
--suffix=SUFFIX     backup suffix (default ~ w/o --backup-dir)
```